# cannot run telegram bot with proxy

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot, http-proxy

I wrote a robot under the server
And I want to run with a proxy
But I miss the following error
mybot is:

```java
     public class StoreBot  extends TelegramLongPollingBot {
            public StoreBot( DefaultBotOptions botOptions) {
                super(botOptions);
            }
        
            public int creatorId() {
                return 0;
            }
        
            public StoreBot() {
            }
                        ....
        }
```

mycode for run bot is:

```java
     ApiContextInitializer.init();
        
     // Create the TelegramBotsApi object to register your bots
     TelegramBotsApi botsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        
     // Set up Http proxy
     DefaultBotOptions botOptions = ApiContext.getInstance(DefaultBotOptions.class);            
        
     botOptions.setProxyHost("2.181.254.198");
     botOptions.setProxyPort(8580);
     // Select proxy type: [HTTP|SOCKS4|SOCKS5] (default: NO_PROXY)
     botOptions.setProxyType(DefaultBotOptions.ProxyType.SOCKS5);
        
     // Register your newly created AbilityBot
     StoreBot bot = new StoreBot(botOptions);
        
     botsApi.registerBot(bot);
```

when run get this error:

```
org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiRequestException: Error removing old webhook
...
Caused by: org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.exceptions.TelegramApiException: Unable to execute deleteWebhook method
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection timed out: connect
```

Comment: "Connection timed out" is self-explanatory. First of all make sure your proxy server works by adding it to desktop Telegram client for example. If there is no problem with the proxy server, check your Internet connection and firewall settings.

Answer (score 0):

```
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom()
            .setProxy(new HttpHost(host, port))
            .build();

    DefaultBotOptions botOptions = new DefaultBotOptions();
    botOptions.setRequestConfig(requestConfig);

    StoreBot bot = new StoreBot(botOptions);
```